# How to disable auto scroll for groups in apple watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to disable the auto scrolling for groups in a WatchApp. Can someone help me?

i have taken two groups in watch storyboard file. one is table groups and second one is white labels group. when scrolling up, both table goup and white labels group are scrolling up together. how to stop scrolling the white labels group(white background).

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your storyboard with the interface controller structure?